# Change the duty cycle of pulses

Tags: pulse, function-generator, duty-cycle

I'm trying to raise the duty cycle of short pulses (about 10%) through the range up to ideally 80% using a potentiometer. I've seen variable pulse generator designs using 555s, but my trigger is external. I'm operating at very low speeds (<40Hz.)

Comment: So are you using sig gen IC, mcu rather than 555?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: I mean are you using mcu such as Arduino or Rpi's PWM pins to generate the pulses. Or signal generator ICs.

Comment: For example, this XY-LPWM signal generator IC/module is very flexible, can even talk UART/Python: How can Rpi4B python UART talk to XY PWM Signal Generators? - RpiSE, Asked 2 years ago, Viewed 941 times
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104779/how-can-rpi4b-python-uart-talk-to-xy-pwm-signal-generators

Comment: The clock comes from an external device I can't really modify. Thank you but I'm not sure I want to use an rPi and Python for this..

Comment: Any one shot IC can do this with a pot. or did you want voltage control..

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean

Comment: the hard part about chaging the duty cycle of a signal is that it requires future knowledge.  how stable is your input frequency?

Comment: Are there any other requirements ?

Comment: I want to change very stable pulses of 10% duty cycle to 80% duty cycle. I don't know what is future knowledge..Do you mean this will only be solved in 100 years? :)

Comment: What kind of requirement?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want to convert an incoming waveform with a 1:9 mark to space ratio into an outgoing waveform with a 4:1 mark to space ratio and make the mark to space ratio adjustable, using a pot, between these two values. The critical question is - does the frequency ever change or is it constant?

Comment: The frequency doesn't change. I have no idea about what 'x:x mark ratio' are. I'm not sure I can make my question clearer. but I think you got it: I want to change the duty cycle of a pulse signal I'm receiving, with a pot.

Comment: @brunobhr "mark-space ratio" is just another way of expressing the duty cycle. If your duty cycle is 10% then the signal is high for 10% of the time and low for the other 90% and hence is said to have a mark space ration of 1-to-9 (1:9). It's another bit of jargon commonly used by EEs. Try googling "555 monostable" I think that's the circuit you want and there are many hit to the search. But, all the ones I've seen have a negative going  trigger. In other words the trigger is high and goes low to initiate the output pulse. You may have to invert your trigger signal.

Comment: So your best advice is using a 555 as monostable, feed my (inverted) pulses to PIN 2 (Trigger) and with the proper configuration, get the modified waveform with the wanted duty cycle at PIN 3 (Output)?

Comment: Yes, your constant frequency makes life much more simple. I'd also suggest a 555 monostable with an inverted input. The monostable then just acts to extend the incoming high parts of each cycle. The high output period of the 555 is then simply set with a RC combination (T=1.1 * R * C) where R is determined by your pot setting with a range limiting resistor placed either side of the pot in series with it.

Comment: Sorry, my error, you only need one range limiting resistor in series with the pot to maintain a minimum value for R.

Comment: Thank you @James, I will try that route and keep this post updated

Comment: @James, I tried this with a 10K pot and 2.2uF and it works perfectly. Just need a bit of tune up on the exact Duty Cycle length, but that's it. Do you want to answer my question?

Comment: Thanks for the offer but I'm not bothered about the points.

Comment: @James: Cool, I'm gonna write my own answer then, as I think changing the duty cycle of a pulse signal can be very useful. If you are game, I'm also trying to find a way reduce the duty cycle..I haven't been able to go below the original signal's DC with that configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @James hints, I've been able to achieve this by using a 555 in Monostable mode like this:
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555_timer.html

I just had to invert my signal at the PIN 2 using a 40106.
Then I used a 10K pot and a 2.2uF cap as R1 and C1 to almost get to 99% Duty Cycle when the pot is turned all the way up.

Answer (score 2):

In response to your last comment...

The way the 555 timer works is that the output (pin 3) is forced to be high whenever the Trigger input (pin2) is low (lower than Vdd/3). So, as you have found, the high output pulse cannot be shorter than the incoming low going trigger pulse.

The way to circumvent this problem is to shorten the incoming trigger pulse to a low going pulse of very short duration. That is the function of C1 and R2 in the circuit below which provide a trigger pulse of about 1ms to trigger the 555.

Diode D1 protects the Trigger input by preventing its voltage rising to more than about 0.7 V above Vdd when the 40106 0utput switches back to a high level.

R1 limits the current being pulled from the 40106 output when its output switches back to a high level.

You'll probably need to reduce your values for R3 & C2 to get a shorter pulse out of the 555 (I think R3 should be no less than 1k) but you will not be able to reduce the duration of the output pulse to less than the duration of the input trigger pulse. If the 1ms (approx) input trigger pulse is still too long for your requirements then you could try a lower value for C1.

Because you'll probably need to reduce your values for R3 & C2 you may need to increase the value of the pot to still achieve the required maximum output pulse duration. - A bit of playing around with component values possibly required!

I haven't built and tested this but it should work, I suggest trying it to see.

[image: 555 monostable]

Comment: Fantastic..I will try and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I've just built the circuit and it worked beautifully. I can now output pulses with a Duty Cycle ranging from 0.5 to 99% at the turn of a pot. This is my dream come true. Don't you really want me to ask a question and answer it? I'd be happy to.

Comment: @brunobhr I'm just happy to get another satisfied customer :-)

Comment: Well that's fantastic James. In case you'd be interested, I'm trying to build an analog sequencer for my little homemade studio: http://cmosorchestra.com. This is gonna help me a lot! Thank you again.